# Is there a way to move an image using jQuery keydown without having the browser scroll up and down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to move an image that is in the middle of a long webpage using jQuery keydown and animate. However, every time I press the up and down key, the browser also scrolls up and down. Is there a way to make the browser static as I move only my image? Thanks!

index.html

```
<img class="pic" src="panda.jpg"/>
```

style.css

```
.pic {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
margin-left: 355px; 
margin-top: -180px;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) 
    case 37:
    $('.pic').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    break;
    case 38:
    $('.pic').animate({top: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    break;
    case 39:
    $('.pic').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
    break;
    case 40:
    $('.pic').animate({top: "+=10px"}, 'fast');
    break;
       }
   });
```

Comment: just `return false;` at the end

Comment: just keep in mind that some users might be relying on the up and down key to scroll the page, and you'd basically destroy that (accessibility) behaviour

Comment: Is there any way around that? How would I restrict that just to the image and not to the whole webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [call `preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) on the event (which you're passing in here as "key"), or return `false` at the end of your function:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    key.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

As a bonus, calling `parseInt()` on `key.which` here is unnecessary as this returns a numeric value anyway.

As this answer was randomly downvoted for now apparent reason, [here is a JSFiddle demo showing `preventDefault()` in action](http://jsfiddle.net/hD2V2/).

Comment: They probably don't like your syntax (which _is_ a bit misleading tbh)

Comment: @blgt I'm not sure what you mean. It's the same syntax the question uses.

Comment: I meant that `return false;` should be inside the `switch`. Otherwise the handler would prevent you from using any key, not just the arrows.